Weight distribution of Gold like binary sequence family and cross-correlation distribution of sequences from the same family of equal weight
I am constructing the Binary Sequences with Gold-like Correlation but Larger Linear Span which was introduced by Boztas and Kumar, full text available here. Here is the construction procedure:
Let $s \geq 1$ is a positive integer, and let $m = 2 s + 1$. Let $\alpha$ is the primitive element of $GF(2^m)$. Let $v_1, v_2, v_3,...,v_{2^m}$ denote the different elements of $GF(2^m)$. Let $Tr(\cdot):GF(2^m)\rightarrow GF(2)$ is the trace function from $GF(2^m)$ to $GF(2)$.
Definition: The binary sequence family $\mathcal{S}$ defined to be the set of $M:=2^m + 1$ sequences $s_i(t)$, $0 \leq t \leq 2^m - 2$, given by
$$
s_i(t)=\begin{cases}
    \ Tr(v_i \alpha^t) + \sum_{l=1}^{s} Tr\big((\alpha^t)^{1+2l}\big) &   \mbox{if}\  1 \leq i \leq 2^m,\\
    Tr(\alpha^t) & \text{if}\  i = 2^m+1.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, consider the case where $s=2$, which means $m = 5$. So, the set $\mathcal{S}$ contains $33$ sequences of period $31$. Now, for a positive integer $j > 0$, let $a_j$ denote the number of sequences of weight $j$ in the set $\mathcal{S}$. So, for $m = 5$, the set of sequences $\mathcal{S}$ has the following weight distribution:
$$a_{12}:= 10\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$a_{16}:= 17\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
$$a_{20}:= 6 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
Now I have the following three questions:
$1:$ Is there a way of mathematically deriving the weight distribution given in $(1),\ (2)$ and $(3)$?
$2:$ Is there a way of directly obtaining the all the sequences of weight $16$ without constructing the entire set $\mathcal{S}$?
$3:$ Is there a way of obtaining the cross-correlation distribution (with frequencies) for the set of sequences of weight $16$?
